# ¿Cómo representar los bytes en las unidades correspondientes?

Tags: condiciones, unix, awk

Tengo estos datos que representan los tamaños de unas DDBB:

```
$ cat sizeDDBB.out
1939701398378,mmm.test1
1701004368433,mmm.test2
736910406686,mmm.test3
726109056943,mmm.test4
653747078583,mmm.test5
...
```

Quisiera que representar los tamaños de las DDBB en TB o MB o GB o el que toque.

Para eso utilizo, o trato de utilizar  `numfmt --to=iec-i` dentro de `awk`

```
awk -F, '{val=numfmt --to=iec-i $1} END {print $1", "$2}' sizeDDBB.out
awk: cmd. line:1: {val=numfmt --to=iec-i $1} END {print $1", "$2}
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error
```

No sé en qué me estoy equivocando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer es lanzar el comando externo `numfmt --to=iec-i` pasándole de parámetro el primer campo.

Esta llamada externa no es automática sino que debes utilizar `"comando" | getline var` para guardar el resultado en `var`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{"numfmt --to=iec-i 2234234" | getline res; print res}'
2.2Mi
```

En tu caso:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {"numfmt --to=iec-i " $1 | getline d; print d,$2}' fichero
1.8Ti,mmm.test1
1.6Ti,mmm.test2
687Gi,mmm.test3
677Gi,mmm.test4
609Gi,mmm.test5
```